# AWS localstack and dotnetcore3.1 lambda functions - cannot create function

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I am trying to run on localstack lambda with dotnetcore3.1. These are the steps

1. Run localstack

```
docker run --name localstack_for_lambda -p 4566:4566 --platform linux -d -e SERVICES=sqs,sns,logs,lambda,iam localstack/localstack
```

2. Create IAM role

```
aws iam --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 create-role --role-name lambda-dotnet-ex --assume-role-policy-document '{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}'
```

3. Attach policy to this role

```
aws iam --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 attach-role-policy --role-name lambda-dotnet-ex --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

4. Create lambda project

```
dotnet new lambda.EmptyFunction -n Simple.Lambda.DotNet
```

5. Compile and publish

```
dotnet build
dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
```

6. Zip lambda files

```
cd publish
zip -r ../function.zip *
```

7. 

```
cd ..
aws lambda --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 create-function --function-name lambda-dotnet-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler Sample.Lambda.DotNet::Sample.Lambda.DotNet.Function::FunctionHandler --runtime dotnetcore3.1 --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-dotnet-ex
```

And this command returns an error:

> An error occurred (500) when calling the CreateFunction operation (reached max retries: 2):

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Does a role definitely exist for the ARN provided?

Comment: Yes because when I run command to create the role I got this response

{
    "Role": {
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": "lambda-dotnet-ex",
        "RoleId": "ivy2j1bp82atq32uolyz",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-dotnet-ex",
        "CreateDate": "2021-11-02T10:34:45.200000+00:00",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": "{Version: 2012-10-17, Statement: [{ Effect: Allow, Principal: {Service: lambda.amazonaws.com}, Action: sts:AssumeRole}]}",
        "MaxSessionDuration": 3600
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

It looks that I was running incorrectly localstack.
I has to be run with privileged mode like this:

```
docker run --name localstack_for_lambda -p 4567:4566 --privileged -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -d -e SERVICES=sqs,sns,logs,lambda,iam -e LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker localstack/localstack:latest
```

then the lambda function is invoked without errors.